# Performing field calculation on new field using partial text from existing field via selection using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, query

I am new to python and am having some issues with the following script.  I want to select all features that have "State R%" in the field "ROADNAME" and populate another field called "Route" with the last part of the text in "ROADNAME".  The text string is STATE RD BB OR STATE RD C for example and in my "Route" field I just want to capture "BB" and "C".

My script below gives me the following error:

for row in upCursor:
RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please [edit] your question to include your actual code as text rather than an image.  When you paste your text you can use the **{ }** button to format as code

Answer (score 2):

Cursors are very powerful - you can embed your selection in the cursor to skip creating a layer.

Also, you don't need to use variables for field names - you can just use the field names themselves to pare down on your code.

Here's how I would write this:

```
centerlines = # path for centerlines here
fields = ['ROADNAME','ROUTE']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(centerlines, fields, where_clause='"ROADNAME" LIKE \'STATE R%\'') as cursor:
    count = 0
    for row in cursor:
        count += 1
        row[1] = row[0].split()[2]
        cursor.updateRow(row)

print count
```

Note that the .split only works as long as every value in "ROADNAME" field is the same format (STATE RD _____)

You can learn more about arc cursors here: [Update Cursors](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm)

Also, make sure your field names are formatted the same exact way that they appear in the table in ArcMap (and use the actual name, not the alias).